# AWS VPC DNS hostname - how to set the inbound resolver value

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

I have been looking into creating a VPC endpoint for a AWS service that I need accessed from another account. I have enabled the private DNS for this. However, I dont see an option to set the endpoint resolver value. How do I set up the value for endpoint resolver? It doesnt allow me it edit this field.

Answer (score 0):

For cross-account communication between VPCs, enabling dns hostname and DNS support should be a great start.

Creating endpoints for your resolver isn’t necessary since the request isn’t from an on-premise environment.